# How to access serverVariable like AUTH_USER in Dot net core

Tags: authentication, iis, .net-core, server-variables

In standard framework, we can context.user.Request.ServerVariables.Get("AUTH_USER");but how to access similar variable in dot net core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/request-features?view=aspnetcore-3.1), it seems you need [IServerVariablesFeature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.features.iservervariablesfeature?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Your code will look like this:

```
var svf = httpContext.Features.Get<IServerVariablesFeature>();
var authUser = svf == null ? "No feature :( Do you have IIS?" : svf["AUTH_USER"];
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is correct, but there is also this shortcut:

```
var authUser = HttpContext.GetServerVariable("AUTH_USER");
```

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontextservervariableextensions.getservervariable?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-httpcontextservervariableextensions-getservervariable(microsoft-aspnetcore-http-httpcontext-system-string)).